# prime path using bfs

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I was solving a question [prime path](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PPATH/)
I am using `bfs` to solve this question

Here is my solution https://ideone.com/GMOyWX

when i am using this function to check for prime ,I am getting correct answer as 6

```
bool isprime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(number); i++) {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when I am using sieves  I am getting wrong answer as 5

```
void sieves(int n) {
    isPrime[0] = false;
    isPrime[1] = false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            for (int j = 2*i; j <= n; j+=i) {

                isPrime[j] = false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong with the sieves?

Comment: Your first function is wrong `isprime(9)` returns true. It should be `i <= sqrt(number)`

Comment: Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think you sieve implementation is correct, so you are doing something wrong in any other place. from your code i see that you are calling your sieve function for every test case. This should not be necessary. In problem statement there is clearly stated that input will be 4 digit two number, so in maximum case, 100000 should be enough limit to generate checking vector if every number is prime or not. 
So just call once your sieve with `100000` once. Prime numbers are fixed number.